# -convertPoint:toCoordinateFromView: method for Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

How do I implement the MapKit method

```
[googleMapView convertPoint:nePoint toCoordinateFromView:pinView];
```

in Google Maps SDK for iOS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
GMSMapView* mapView = ...;
CGPoint point = ...;
...
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = 
    [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint: point];
```

In this case `point` should be relative to the map view.

If you have a point relative to another view (eg `pinView` in your case), you'd need to convert that into a point relative to the map view first. You could do that with the following:

```
UIView* pinView = ...;
CGPoint pinViewPoint = ...;
...
CGPoint mapViewPoint = [pinView convertPoint: pinViewPoint toView: mapView];
```

So combining it all together:

```
GMSMapView* mapView = ...;
UIView* pinView = ...;
CGPoint pinViewPoint = ...;
...
CGPoint mapViewPoint = [pinView convertPoint: pinViewPoint toView: mapView];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = 
    [mapView.projection coordinateForPoint: mapViewPoint];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what is pinViewPoing in last sample?

Comment: @Mecid: It's the point relative to the `pinView` that you want converted - named `nePoint` in your example code.

Comment: @SaxonDruce Hi! I exactly want to do the opposite of it. I want to convert the marker's location to screen point. I have tried with projection but sometimes it gives me negative value. Do you have any idea about that ?

Comment: @NimishaPatel Hi Nimisha, the reverse is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066567/how-to-get-cgpoint-of-location-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios If that's not working, you might want to post a separate question with a sample of your code?