# How to get CGPoint of location with google maps sdk for iOS?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

How to get CGPoint of location with google maps sdk for iOS ?
I need add pinview on user location.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's basically the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007528/convertpoint-tocoordinatefromview-method-for-google-maps-ios-sdk), for example:

```c
GMSMapView* mapView = ...;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = ...;
...
CGPoint point = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate: coordinate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to your question do you want to convert the userlocation into the cgpoint, is that..
try use this.

```
CGPoint newCenter = [self.map convertCoordinate:coord toPointToView:self.map];
```

Regards.

Comment: I need get CGPoint of window from userlocation on the map.

Comment: sorry, i didn't got your question at the first time, if you are asking for converting from userlocation coordinates to cgpoint, then there is a method, i have edited my code. Hope it helps.