# Convert CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates to CGPoint Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have a Google Map in iOS Swift app. And i am trying to get CGPoint position for my current user coordinate so that i can apply some animation around. But I am not able to get position in CGPoint for my coordinates.

I am basically trying to add Pulse Animation for my current user marker. Here is my code for animation -

```
class Pulsing: CALayer {
    var animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()

    var initialPulseSacle:Float = 0
    var nextPluseAfter:TimeInterval = 0
    var animationDuration:TimeInterval = 1.5
    var radius:CGFloat = 200
    var numberOfPulse:Float = Float.infinity

    override init(layer: Any) {
        super.init(layer: layer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    init(numberOfPulse:Float = Float.infinity, radius:CGFloat, position:CGPoint){
            super.init()
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            self.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            self.opacity = 0
            self.radius = radius
            self.position = position

            self.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: radius*2, height: radius*2)
            self.cornerRadius = radius

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
                self.setupAnimationGroup()

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.add(self.animationGroup, forKey: "pulse")
                }
            }

    }
    func createScaleAnimation () -> CABasicAnimation{
        let scaleAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transferm.scale.xy")
        scaleAnimation.fromValue = NSNumber(value: initialPulseSacle)
        scaleAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: 1)
        scaleAnimation.duration = animationDuration
        return scaleAnimation
    }
    func createOpacityAnimation () -> CAKeyframeAnimation{
        let opacityAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        opacityAnimation.duration = animationDuration
        opacityAnimation.values = [4.0, 8.0, 0]
        opacityAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.2, 1]
        return opacityAnimation
    }

    func setupAnimationGroup(){
        self.animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        self.animationGroup.duration = animationDuration + nextPluseAfter
        self.animationGroup.repeatCount = numberOfPulse
        let defaultCurve = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault)
        self.animationGroup.timingFunction = defaultCurve
        self.animationGroup.animations = [createScaleAnimation(),createOpacityAnimation()]
    }

}
```

And then this is how I am calling it in my setup marker method -

```
func setuplocationMarker(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,address:String) {
        locationMarker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        locationMarker.map = viewMap
        locationMarker.title = address
        locationMarker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
        locationMarker.icon = GMSMarker.markerImage(with: UIColor.red)
        locationMarker.opacity = 0.75

        let pulse = Pulsing(numberOfPulse: 1, radius: 80, position:CGPoint(x: CGFloat(Float(coordinate.latitude)), y: CGFloat(Float(coordinate.longitude))))
        pulse.animationDuration = 0.8
        pulse.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(pulse, below: locationMarker.layer)
    }
```

With this code it shows the pulse animation at the top let corner, not around the location marker. How do i get the correct cgpoint position for my marker. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get CGPoint of location with google maps sdk for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066567/how-to-get-cgpoint-of-location-with-google-maps-sdk-for-ios)

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15013705/3824808

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly convert a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` to a `CGPoint` by using the latitude and longitude. Most map API's will provide a method to do this for you.

Google's Map API provides [pointFromCoordinate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_projection.html#a8822e27ca2557b7f2f484781f956ff5c) which creates a `CGPoint` in the `GMSMapView`'s frame. This is a method on `GMSProjection` which you obtain from the 'projection' property on the `GMSMapView`.

You can then translate that into the coordinate space of another `UIView` by using Apple's [convertPoint:toView:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452694-convert)
For example:

```
let location = mapView.userLocation
let point = mapView.projection.pointFromCoordinate(location.coordinate)
let pointInNewView = newView.convert(point, from: mapView)
```