# GoogleMaps SDK Cordova distance in pixel?

Tags: cordova, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the google maps sdk on cordova. 
I have the position in lat/lng of the top-left corner of my screen and the position of a point in pixel screen.
I would like to find the position of this point in lat/lng.

For this, i'd like to know the conversion of 1px in lat and 1px in lng according to the zoom map level.

Do you know how to do that ?
Thank you a lot.

UPDATE CODE :

```
    $("#icon").draggable({
             helper : 'clone',
        stop:function(event,ui) {
            var wrapper = $("#container-emote").offset();
            var borderLeft = parseInt($("#container-emote").css("border-left-width"),10);
            var borderTop = parseInt($("#container-emote").css("border-top-width"),10);
            var pos = ui.helper.offset();
            $scope.createEmote(pos.left - wrapper.left - borderLeft + 40, -(pos.top - wrapper.top - borderTop)+185,2 );
        }
        });

$scope.createEmote = function(a,b,c) {
                var height = screen.height;
                b = height - b;
                map.fromPointToLatLng([a, b], function (point) {
                alert('lat' + point[0] + ' lng:' + point[1]);
            });
        };
```

SOLUTION :

Well in fact a and b where NaN at the launch, here is the final :

```
$scope.createEmote = function(a,b,c) {
                var height = screen.height;
                b = height - b;
                if (!isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b)){
                        map.fromPointToLatLng([a , b], function (point) {
                        console.log('mousedown lat' + point[0] + ' lng:' + point[1]);
                    });
                }
        };
```

Comment: You can convert your point in pixel (point) coordinates into lat/lon using the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007528/convertpoint-tocoordinatefromview-method-for-google-maps-ios-sdk

Comment: I just find out i just have to convert a and b into integer ??

Comment: What values are you getting when you log a, b, lat, lng?

Comment: a is x of screen and b y of screen in pixels. But i guess they are string and i have to put them in integer or something ?

Comment: because it works when i do map.fromPointToLatLng([100, 100], function (point) { but not when i try to convert var into integer like map.fromPointToLatLng([parseInt(a), parseInt(b)], function (point) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this was a duplicate of the earlier question I linked to in the comments. However since you're using Cordova, that changes it a bit.

If you're using [this Cordova Google Maps plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps), then have a look at `fromPointToLatLng()` described here:

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Map

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/wiki/Map.fromPointToLatLng

Comment: Update in 2018: current document URL is https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.3.0/class/Map/fromPointToLatLng/README.md